# How to get total experience in terms of date object

Tags: date, datediff

I have a condition here in which I will have total experience in terms of month and year. For example, two drop down will be there for asking total number of experience in month and year. So if I am working from 1 Jan 2012, then I will write total experience as 3 year and 11 months. Now I have to convert this 3 year and 11 months into date format so that I can save this into database

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "total experience"? In this context, I really have no idea what it might even mean.

Comment: total work experience is just a field nothing else whose value will be given in months and years

Comment: You can't have an *interval* as a date. You probably want to rather either store start/end pairs, or interval.

Comment: Suppose I am working in a industry and have a total experience of 3 year and 11 months. Now I want to write a program so that I can get my Date of joining

Comment: Would not it be simpler to ask for an end date for a particular experience instead of an interval and calculating the end date from the interval?

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3-11' YEAR_MONTH` ?

Comment: @eggyal- Yes, the same
RequiredDate =CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3-11' YEAR_MONTH

Comment: No, I mean that is the MySQL expression you can use.

Comment: I do not want to run any query, I have to change this interval into a date and this date will be saved in the database

Comment: And how exactly do you propose inserting data without running a query?  Just use that expression within your `INSERT` query.

Comment: @eggyal- Sir I am getting a webRequest in which I will get total experience as "2.9" which means 2 year and 9 months of experience. Now I have to use this total experience to get the joining date .I think I have explained you ??

Comment: And I think I have explained how to do what you want to you.  But if you don't want to listen, that's fine by me.  Ciao.

Answer (score 1):

You could use java.util.Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

As a word of caution, the day field would be set to today's date. Check the intended behaviour if the current day is outside of the bounds for the target month. For example, setting the month to February when calendar has a day field of 30. It might be wise to set the day to a known, valid value for every month (eg: 1) before setting the month and year.

Comment: Yes Naveen that's what I was looking for, and also i will set the valid date 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's [date_sub()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function or `<date> - interval <expression> unit` syntax to subtract an interval from a date.

```
select date_sub(curdate(),interval '3-11' YEAR_MONTH) as start_date
```

UPDATE:

Following the conversation between the OP and @eggyal, the OP need to replace the period in the incoming data with - and construct an insert statement as follows:

```
insert into mytable (...,join_date,...) values (...,date_sub(curdate(),interval '3-11' YEAR_MONTH),...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**DATE_SUB()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function:

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR), INTERVAL 11 MONTH);
```

Comment: There is a YEAR_MONTH period as well, no need for 2 subtractions. This way you arrive to the same answer I have.

Comment: @Shadow: Or indeed the same comment I posted 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @eggyal I was busy writing an answer, have not read your comment. Why did not you post it as an answer?